# Java code will not compile

Tags: java, syntax

I have this piece of code but when I try to compile it, I just receive errors. could anyone spot the sytnax error, or what I'm doing wrong?

```
public double getTotalBalance(ArrayList<String> accounts)
{
double sum = 0;
while (studentNames.size() > 0)
{
BankAccount account = accounts.remove(O); // Not recommended
sum = sum + account.getBalance();
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: Post the complete program, I am seeing studentNames is not declare? what is BankAccount?

Comment: If that is your entire file, then the problem is that you cannot declare a "bare" method in Java.  Every method must be inside a class.

Comment: accounts.remove(O); you have a typo this is a capital O, i think you mean 0

Comment: What you are doing on the sixth line is not recommended.

Comment: What is error text? Where is context of the program? Dude, We're not psychics!

Comment: @EmilVikström - So the problem is the comment?  :-)

Comment: @Ivan - apart from Jon Skeet :-)

Comment: it was a textbook exercise, sorry if its misleading in someway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the right code is:

```
public double getTotalBalance(ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts)
{
    double sum = 0;
    while (accounts.size() > 0)
    {
         BankAccount account = accounts.remove(0); // Not recommended
         sum = sum + account.getBalance();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the `accounts.remove(O)`. As you are passing `ArrayList<String>` accounts ,from this the accounts `Arraylist` contains only `strings`?.